# About do-while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in python. But somewehere in my code there is a problem and I know it's in the while loop. What I want to do is, whenever the user types anything but +,-,*,/ I want the program to automatically ask again for operation and start over this process. The code:

```
n1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
n2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

def add(n1,n2): return n1 + n2
def sub(n1,n2): return n1 - n2
def div(n1,n2): return n1 / n2
def mult(n1,n2): return n1 * n2
def exp(n1,n2): return n1 ** n2

print("Choose operation (+, -, *, /, ^): ")
operation = input()

while operation != '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' or '^':
    print("Invalid operation, try again (+, -, *, /, ^): ")
    break

else:   
    if operation == '+':
        print(n1,"+",n2,"=",add(n1,n2))
    
    elif operation == '-':
        print(n1,"-",n2,"=",sub(n1,n2))
    
    elif operation == '*':
        print(n1,"*",n2,"=",mult(n1,n2))
    
    elif operation == '/':
        print(n1,"/",n2,"=",div(n1,n2))
    
    elif operation == "^":
        print(n1,"^",n2,"=",exp(n1,n2))
```

Comment: `operation != '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' or '^'` does not do what you think ...

Comment: Oh I see! But, what is the right way to do it...? (I thought the or gate was correct)

Comment: Try the and : for if operation is +, then operation != ‘-‘ is true. What you want is operation not + and not - …

Comment: I think I got it. If again have a question, I'll message here! Thank you!